# mapItemForCurrentLocation does not find my current location

Tags: ios

I am working on the mapkit in ios where I have to trace my route from my current location.
Now, I had assigned my current location i.e. latitude and longitude  using the simulator(Debug->location->custom location) but when I try to trace my source I get my source location as nil and due to which I am not able to get the route.

[directionsRequest setSource:[MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation]];

Can any one suggest the possible solution for my problem

Code

MKDirectionsRequest *directionsRequest = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];

```
MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:thePlacemark];

[directionsRequest setSource:[MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation]];

[directionsRequest setDestination:[[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark]];

directionsRequest.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportTypeAutomobile;

MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:directionsRequest];
```

Comment: can you post your code here

Comment: You say "I get my source location as nil" -- how are you determining this exactly?  Where is this code executed?  Do you see the blue dot at the location you set in the simulator?  How is thePlacemark set?  Are you calling calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MapView then there is one delegate method in which you will get your current location without using CLLocationManager.

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad
  {
    mapView.delegate=self;
  }   

 -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation

{
   `enter code here`  //Here MKUserLocation will give you current Location and every time will method will call when the location is change...'

}
```

and if you want only user location then use

```
 MKUserLocation *userlocation=mapView.userlocation
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting nil location because you are testing it in simulator please run it on real device

Comment: i think you are getting nil because you are testing it in simulator please run it on real device @Nexttric

Comment: Location can be simulated in the simulator -- a real device is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/ states mapItemForCurrentLocation does not contain coordinate data for privacy reasons, but here is a simple workaround if you are using a map view and showsUserLocation true:

```
MKUserLocation* userLocation = self.mapView.userLocation;
MKMapItem* mapItemForCurrentLocation;
if(userLocation.isUpdating && userLocation.isBeingUpdated){
    mapItemForCurrentLocation = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:[[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:userLocation.location.coordinate addressDictionary:nil]];
    mapItemForCurrentLocation.name = @"Current Location";
}
```